# Remove all rows (for a given column value) from a dataframe if column max value is less than a defined threshold

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

Apologies if the question heading is a bit confusing. I am new to pyspark and am dealing with the following problem:

Let's say I have a dataframe with date, product and total_orders as three columns and I have this dataframe for a period of 3 days. So something like

```
date           product      orders

2022-01-01      whisky        11
2022-01-01      rum           100
2022-01-01      bourbon       5
2022-01-02      whisky        20
2022-01-02      rum           150
2022-01-02      bourbon       7 
2022-01-03      whisky        30
2022-01-03      rum           7
2022-01-03      bourbon       3
```

I want to filter out any product whose maximum number of orders are less than 10. So in the case of dataframe above all the rows containing bourbon as a product will be filtered out as the max(orders of bourbon) < 10.

Output:

```
    date       product      orders

2022-01-01      whisky        11
2022-01-01      rum           100
2022-01-02      whisky        20
2022-01-02      rum           150
2022-01-03      whisky        30
2022-01-03      rum           7
```

What is the best way to go about it? I have been looking int Window function in pyspark but have not been able to get it right.

I have created a windowspec like this

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(groupedDf['product']).orderBy(groupedDf['orders'].desc())
```

but having trouble filtering out the dataframe rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can first find the `max orders` for each `product`, and then filter based on that value.

```
df = df.selectExpr('*', 'max(orders) over (partition by product) as max_orders') \
    .filter('max_orders >= 10').drop('max_orders')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi I have edited the question to make my intent more clearer. Apologies for the confusion. Even though rum has orders less than 10 for 2022-01-03, I still need to preserve that row as rums orders' maximum value i.e 150 is > 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the case for a window function.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
window = Window.partitionBy("product").orderBy(F.col("orders").desc())
df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(window)).filter("rn < 10")
```

Comment: Hmm not sure that it works. It is removing a lot of unwanted rows from the dataset. The original dataset is pretty big and by this logic I end up removing certain rows of products that should remain. I want to remove the entire product group whose max does not satisfy the threshold and leave others untouched.

Comment: The suggested solution does 1 thing.
for every product that order by its orders (descending) it will leave only the TOP 9 orders. (need to change <= so TOP 10).

Comment: Hi I have edited the question to make my intent more clearer. Apologies for the confusion. Even though rum has orders less than 10 for 2022-01-03, I still need to preserve that row as rums orders' maximum value i.e 150 is > 10.